# QR code not being processed with hard return consistently across devices

Tags: qr-code

Processing a string to genrate a qr code with the barby gem

```
Barby::QrCode:0x00007f903399aed8 @data="8076809574693\r\n8076809574693\r\n8076809574693\r\n4017100364013\r\n4017100364013\r\n3017760002707\r\n8076809517706\r\n8013355999488\r\n", @level=:q, @size=nil
```

is generating a QR code as a PNG file which is read correctly by off-the-shelf android apps.  However, when run against a [Honeywell](https://sps.honeywell.com/us/en/products/productivity/barcode-scanners/presentation/vuquest-3320g-hands-free-scanner) 3320 hand-held scanner, it is being recognized as simply a string of digits

what other approaches could be taken to generate the hard return?

[image]

Comment: The Honeywell 3320 scanner has tons of configuration options. If you run it in keyboard mode, it adds a CR after every scanned code, and likely removes CR and LF in the scanned data. What's your configuration?

Comment: It is in keyboard emulation. I was told to insert /r/n after each code, but as the image attests, no dice... 'likely removes CR and LF in the scanned data'; your assumption seems correct.  How does the scanner know when to stop scanning one code and consider the next?